# How to convert from PDF to XPS?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, xps, acrobat

I use the following method to print a XPS file with adobe acrobat:

```
private void GenerateXPS(String filename)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/t " + filename + ".pdf" + " " + "\"Microsoft XPS Document Writer\"";
            proc.Start();
        }
```

But the problem is, the Microsoft XPS Document writer needs a filename where to store the document. Now I'm asked to enter this filename by Adobe Acrobat, but I want to pass this filename as well in the arguments. Or if this is not possible just use the same filename. Is this possible?

Comment: Why is there a close vote? Explanation would be nice!

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to print a PDF *to* XPS (which is what the code looks like) or print an XPS to PDF (which is what the title/text seems to say)?

Comment: @Richard I'm trying to convert from PDF to XPS.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't mandatory that you use acrobat, you might try printing the file directly to the Microsoft XPS Document writer. You can do this without the UI popping up. (see [Feng Yuan's blog post for more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2005/09/16/469076.aspx))

Comment: hmm this code looks weird, are you sure that I can run it ina WPF environment?

Comment: @Roflcoptr I believe that is C code on that blog post. But it gives you an idea of how you might attack the problem in C#.

Comment: Yes if I would be more skilled maybe ;)